# Java: Allowed statements after labels

Tags: java, syntax

I'm playing around with Java Syntax, so this is question arises purely from curiosity. This piece of code:

```
http://www.google.com
Object val = 5 <- 4;
```

does **not** compile, because a label (`http`) "must be followed by a statement". The following two variants do compile:

```
http://www.google.com
{ Object val = 5 <- 4; }
```

and

```
Object val;
http://www.google.com
val = 5 <- 4;
```

In both cases, I switched from a declaration to an expression.
This makes me wonder what exactly is a "statement" in Java, but the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)
states:

> In addition to expression statements, there are two other kinds of statements: declaration statements and control flow statements. A declaration statement declares a variable.

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) just says (on labels) that

> The Identifier is declared to be the label of the immediately contained Statement.

It does not say anything about "expression statements".

Did I miss something, or is this just an unclear/incorrect specification?

Comment: What is that expression `"http://www.google.com"`?

Comment: @MykhayloKopytonenko It's not an expression, it's just some text in a comment. The label is `http:`, and then the `//` starts a line comment. Tricky tricky! :)

Comment: The code is nuts!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you read chapter 14 of the JLS a bit more carefully, you'll find that a LocalVariableDeclarationStatement is *not* a Statement. Not very intuitive of them, is it?

Specifically, in [JLS 14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2), we see that:

- a Block essentially consists of zero or more BlockStatements
- a BlockStatement is one of:

  - LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
  - ClassDeclaration
  - Statement

So a LocalVariableDeclarationStatement is not a descendant of Statement in the hierarchy, but rather a sibling. They are both types of BlockStatements.

A label must be followed by a true Statement — that is, the specific subtype of BlockStatement that is neither a LocalVariableDeclarationStatement nor a ClassDeclaration. The various subtypes of Statement are listed in [14.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5). You will not find LocalVariableDeclarationStatement among them, though you will find ExpressionStatement as a subtype of StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement.

Comment: This really is an extremely unintuitive choice of naming. The quoted Section is only marginally different in Java 8 [JLS 14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) (the notation for multiple statements has changed a bit to Array-like "[]", and links have been added).

Comment: Ok, JLS 14.2 applies because the function body is a block statement... Thanks!